# JSON in Nginx Configuration

Tags: postgresql, nginx

It is possible to return JSON from PostgreSQL using `ngx_postgres` and `ngx_rds_json`. Is it possible to insert JSON back into PostgreSQL (without external scripting)?

Comment: What do you mean "insert JSON back to PostgreSQL?  You mean store JSON in PostgreSQL as a JSON or text field?  Or convert to a valid type and insert into a table?

Answer (score 1):

Try experimental module [ngx_pgcopy](https://github.com/AntonRiab/ngx_pgcopy).
Samples how to do it you can found in [slim_middle_samples](https://github.com/AntonRiab/slim_middle_samples).
You need examples slim_middle_samples/sql/1.import.export.sql and nginx.conf/import.export.nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends heavily on what you are trying to do.  This is a very generic question and it isn't clear at all what is being asked, but in this case I will answer giving both approaches so that others can make decisions when they see it.

**Storing JSON in PostgreSQL**

In PostgreSQL 9.2, PostgreSQL comes with a native JSON type.  This has been backported to 9.1 by Andrew Dunstan and available at https://bitbucket.org/adunstan/json_91

For earlier versions your only option is to use a text field.  The JSON type is not very full-featured.  It does validation and that's about all.  You can't convert easily from JSON to other types at least out of the box.  If all you are doing is storing free-form data (Mongo-like) this may be almost sufficient for you, but you will likely need `plv8js` installed to do anything particularly useful with it (such as, for example, indexing json fields based on whether a given property is present and if so what its value is).

**Manipulating JSON in PostgreSQL**

PostgreSQL comes with no out of the box facilities for manipulating JSON.  However, PostgreSQL is also one of the most, if not the most, programmable RDBMS in the world so anything is possible.

The simplest option is perhaps to install `plv8js` and write functions which manipulate the json in javascript in your backend database.  You could then hide the logic behind a view with triggers or the like or use a stored procedure interface.  This wouldn't be external scripting so much as it would be data presentation functionality you'd code in the database.

You could also use `plperlu` or `plpython` to write the functions also if Javascript isn't your cup of tea.